# What is the equivalent of the application-local.properties file in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

It seems to me that in Spring Boot the local profile is a de facto standard for local development.

Is there a way in Quarkus that one has a `application-dev.properties`, which is equivalent to the application.properties....

My goal is to store secrect information necessary for local development, which should not be committed to git... I have not found anything from searching and only found a ".env" file in the .gitignore.

What would be the correct Quarkus solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus supports [profile aware files](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-aware-files) to configure the application.
The default profiles are:

> - dev - Activated when in development mode (i.e. quarkus:dev)
> - test - Activated when running tests
> - prod - The default profile when not running in development or test mode

So configuration values in `application-dev.properties` file will be activated in development mode.

Some newsworthy information from the reference:

> In this style, the configuration names in the profile aware file do not need to be prefixed with the profile name.
>
> Properties in the profile aware file have priority over profile aware properties defined in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your secrets in a .env file and utilize property expressions in your application{-dev}.properties. For default behavior, Quarkus retrieves configuration properties from multiple sources:

- System Properties

```
./mvnw quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.datasource.password=youshallnotpass
```

- Environment variables

```
export DB_PASS=youshallnotpass
java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```

- .env file

```
DB_PASS=youshallnotpass
```

application.properties or application-dev.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASS}
```

**The recommended approach for local development is to use the .env file.**

Another option is to initiate Quarkus with the 'local' profile using the following command:

```
./mvnw quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.profile=local
```

This will make use of the application-local.properties, which should be added to your .gitignore.

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources